# rostopic list works but rostopic echo does not

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running the ROS core on a mobile robot and am using ssh to monitor it from a workstation.  On the workstation I have ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP configured per the wiki's instructions to point at the robot's IP address.  "rostopic list" works correctly and shows me the correct list of topics.  Unfortunately, "rostopic echo" is silent, and "rxgraph" also implies the workstation is not connected to the host.

The question: under what circumstances could rostopic list work and rostopic echo not work?

(I'm familiar with the relevant sections of the wiki (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup, for example), but they're not answering this question for me.)

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48240/rostopic-list-works-but-rostopic-echo-does-not/) by [Tom Sgouros](https://answers.ros.org/users/1205/tom-sgouros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-11-13

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Sgouros](https://answers.ros.org/users/1205/tom-sgouros/) on 2012-11-13**:
Just to elaborate, I can edit /etc/hosts on both machines to make this work, but the network setup page implies I should be able to do this by setting ROS_IP, which does not seem to work.  I don't have su privilege on all the machines I want to use.

**Comment by [Mattster](https://answers.ros.org/users/77885/mattster/) on 2021-07-15**:
Suffering the same problem in 2021, but I do have su access so I edited /etc/hosts and its started working.  None of the rest of the ROS_ID= stuff worked.  Why does this make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`$ROS_IP` on your workstation should be your *workstation*'s IP address, not the robot's.

`rostopic list` is just talking to the master, whereas `rostopic echo` needs to be able to communicate with the publishers.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BaBui](https://answers.ros.org/users/37344/babui/) on 2022-06-15**:
Thank you so much. It worked. I forgot to set ROS_IP on master, and
slave robot

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ROS_IP and $ROS_HOSTNAME basically tell the nodes running on a computer on which address they are reachable from the outside. You need to set only one of those. Whatever works better in your network. (To be absolutely sure and if you can use static IPs, i prefer using IP addresses)

So make sure, that you can ping in both directions and set $ROS_IP on the server and the workstation each to their externally reachable addresses.

jbohren already mentioned what constellation can lead to the observed behaviour. rostopic list is completely independent from the setting of $ROS_IP. It only needs an correctly set $ROS_MASTER_URI. :)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I undergo the same problem.
You also should set $ROS_IP on mobile robot.
It works.

---

Originally posted by [Younghyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14156/younghyo/) with karma: 15 on 2014-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just had this issue when I moved my computers onto a new network, where they got assigned new nonstatic IPs by DHCP.   The fix which worked for me was:

set ROS_HOSTNAME on robot PC to its own ip,

set ROS_HOSTNAME on base PC to its own ip

set ROS_IP on robot PC to base IP

set ROS_MASTER_URI to base IP:11311 both machines.

---

Originally posted by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) with karma: 120 on 2015-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lhnguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/27813/lhnguyen/) on 2017-06-13**:
Thanks for your answer! I got headache with other solutions but this does help me!

**Comment by [Harestew](https://answers.ros.org/users/52298/harestew/) on 2020-05-02**:
This worked for me, either! For my case ROS_MASETER_URI setting for base machine itself was not necessary. Also ufw disable(turn off firewall) and etc/hosts file did not affect my result.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding the ros server to the /etc/hosts file on the client worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas10111](https://answers.ros.org/users/23181/thomas10111/) with karma: 81 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check your settings in both terminal. We had same problem and problem was in :

We had in 1st terminal `ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311` - in this terminal runs roscore
and in 2nd terminal  `ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311` - in this terminal runs urg_node

**In matlab we receive using rostopic list all nodes but if we use rostopic echo /scan, we are not able to receive data.**

**there is our solution:**
best way how eliminate similiar mistakes is add few lines to .bashrc file

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.10
export ROS_IP=              (empty data)
```

and it works!

**and if you want use matlab**

192.168.1.11 - our PC with matlab
192.168.1.10 RPI with ROS and sensors

```
setenv('ROS_MASTER_URI','http://192.168.1.10:11311')
setenv('ROS_IP','192.168.1.11')
setenv('ROS_HOSTNAME','192.168.1.11')
```

---

Originally posted by [Wiew](https://answers.ros.org/users/29043/wiew/) with karma: 53 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

even after the correct settings of ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP to the base workstation you would some times not receive the data and rostopic list works but not rostopic echo

in order to work on this issue you'll have to add an exception in your firewall settings for the robot's IP connection or disable the firewall using the command :
sudo ufw disable

it should definitely work !

---

Originally posted by [sai krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/29950/sai-krishna/) with karma: 111 on 2019-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkAi9](https://answers.ros.org/users/74363/markai9/) on 2021-05-11**:
"sudo ufw disable" solved my case

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case it was a matter of my client not being able to resolve the IP address of my server. I was able to verify this by subscribing to a topic and then checking the info about that topic:

```
$rostopic info /gazebo/model_states

Type: gazebo_msgs/ModelStates

Publishers: 
 * /gazebo (http://my-workstation:42193/)

Subscribers: 
 * /rostopic_117_1574085827847 (http://132.11.11.111:40064/)
```

I had passed 132.11.11.111 to my client as ROS_MASTER_URI but my server publishes as 'my-workstation' and not 132.11.11.111. It's clear then that the Ros Master was unable to connect the topic listener and publisher to listen and publish to the same port because it cant resolve what 'my-workstation' is referring to.

So my solution was to add

```
132.11.11.111 my-workstation
```

to the end of etc/hosts on my client and now it works

---

Originally posted by [benwex93](https://answers.ros.org/users/38364/benwex93/) with karma: 51 on 2019-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1